# Paper recommender system

Tags: publications, research-process, google-scholar

Does anyone know a tool that gives paper recommendations based on a user defined list of papers?

For example, if I've read papers A, B and C, I would like to find all papers related to A, B and C sorted by relevance. In this list a paper that cites all A, B and C or that is cited by all 3 should rank higher than a paper that is related to just one of them.

EDIT: Some people suggested to use Google Scholar. The problem with Google Scholar is that it gives you papers related to just one article. If I have a base of 5 papers for my bibliography and I want to expand it, then I have to search for papers related to each of them individually and soon the number of options will become huge. I would prefer to have a smarter tool that analyze the links between the 5 papers and recommends articles related to all of them together. This would save a lot of time.

Comment: GooSchol does it for 1 paper, or for your papers.  It shouldn't be too hard to write a script that takes the "related papers" for each paper in the list and process them.

Comment: Google Scholar doesn't provide an API and it's quite illegal to crawl it with scripts.

Comment: "This would save a lot of time". Of course it would. But then what would you do during your literature review? Part of the work you have to do during the PhD, is to learn to scan the literature fast and efficiently. On the other hand, if you use Google scholar and find the top-5 authors and follow them (new articles + citations) then the recommended articles it suggests are quite good.

Comment: @Alexandros There is a compromise in every innovation. If planes weren't there, there would be no plane crashes...

Comment: Here's a (negative) [review](http://docear.org/papers/research_paper_recommender_system_evaluation--a_quantitative_literature_survey.pdf) of such methods.

Comment: _I would prefer to have a smarter tool that analyze the links between the 5 papers and recommends articles related to all of them together. This would save a lot of time._ — Sounds like an excellent topic for a PhD thesis.  Go for it!

Comment: I've already started my PhD on something else :) But I consider doing this as a side project.

Comment: Mendeley has recently started to send me paper suggestions based on my saved papers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with such a tool. But, if you reading an article on a scientific website such as [http://www.sciencedirect.com/](http://ScienceDirect), a list of recommended or related papers will appear on the right hand side. Some of these recommended papers are very related, cited or been cited by the article you are reading. Google Scholar will list all papers that have cited a certain that too. I hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe this is more appropriate as a comment?

Comment: The problem with Google Scholar and others is that they give you papers related to just one article. If I have a base of 5 papers for my bibliography and I want to expand it, then I have to search for papers related to each of them individually and soon the number of options will become huge. I would prefer to have a smarter tool that analyze the links between the 5 papers and recommends articles related to all of them together. This would save a lot of time.

Comment: Note, also, that sciencedirect is Elsevier, and recommends only other Elsevier papers.